# strftime warning error in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, time

I have a method in a .c file that returns the modified time of a file.

```
int lastModifiedTime(char *filePath)
{
    struct stat attrib;
    stat(filePath, &attrib);
    char datestring[256];
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&attrib.st_mtime);
    strftime(datestring, sizeof(datestring), "%s", tm);
    return atoi(datestring);
}
```

But I get this compile warning, how do I fix it?

```
client/file_monitor.c:227:5: warning: ISO C does not support the '%s' gnu_strftime format [-Wformat=]
 strftime(datestring, sizeof(datestring), "%s", tm);
 ^
```

Comment: Are you using gcc? What command-line options are you giving it? Do you *want* to use the "%s"` specifier (which gives you the number of seconds since 1970)?

Comment: yes i do want epoch time

Comment: And the other questions I asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has to be one of the more convoluted and inefficient ways of writing:

```
int lastModifiedTime(const char *filePath)
{
    struct stat attrib;
    if (stat(filePath, &attrib) != 0)
        return -1;
    return attrib.st_mtime;
}
```

However, to answer the question:

- You get the error when you specify `-pedantic` (and not when you don't, even with all the other stringent warnings shown):

  ```
  $ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -pedantic -c stt.c
  stt.c: In function ‘lastModifiedTime’:
  stt.c:14:5: error: ISO C does not support the ‘%s’ gnu_strftime format [-Werror=format=]
       strftime(datestring, sizeof(datestring), "%s", tm);
       ^
  cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
  $
  ```
- As stated, by omitting the `-pedantic`, you avoid that error.  Assuming `-pedantic` is required, then you seem to be hosed.  The nearest I can get is avoiding an error but still getting a warning:

  ```
  $ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -Wno-error=format= -c stt.c
  stt.c: In function ‘lastModifiedTime’:
  stt.c:14:5: warning: ISO C does not support the ‘%s’ gnu_strftime format [-Wformat=]
       strftime(datestring, sizeof(datestring), "%s", tm);
       ^
  $
  ```
- I'm probably suffering from a lack of imagination, but I can't suppress the warning.  I've tried (with GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04):

  - `-Wnoformat`
  - `-Wno-format`
  - `-Wno-format=`
  - `-Wnoerror=format=`
  - `-Wnoformat=`

  But none of these was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

According to this (and your error):
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

`%s` isn't a supported format option. I'm not sure what you're using `%s` for, but maybe `%S` is what you're looking for.

Comment: i'm trying to get epoch time